# Can't download macOS High Sierra once again

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I've macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G8023) installed. The icon of the app, "Installation of macOS High Sierra" is available in `/Application`:

```
ls -al /Applications | grep macOS
drwxr-xr-x@   4 root   wheel    136  8 июн  2018 Установка macOS High Sierra.appdownload
```

("Установка" means "Installation" in my localized OS X version)

The app start should download installer according to my expectation. But it doesn't. On the other hand "Installation of macOS High Sierra" is not included in the list of my purchased application in App Store. I can see previous versions in this list (OS X El Capitan, OS X Yosemite etc.), but not macOS High Sierra and macOS Sierra.

I also tried to find "Installation of macOS High Sierra" using App Store's search.

Both macOS High Sierra and macOS Sierra are absent in the results. Could you please advise how to download macOS High Sierra installation application?

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/in/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12 this is High Sierra. What are you unable to do? Also you can use https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204904 to install latest or last versions etc

Comment: `macOS High Sierra.appdownload` would suggest a partially downloaded file. if ankiiii's link causes any issues, deleting the partial may help.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've successfully downloaded it by the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the link available on the Apple Support document, [How to upgrade to macOS High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208969) to download the installer for macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

> ### 4. Download macOS High Sierra
>
> > For the strongest security and latest features, find out whether you can [upgrade to macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201475), the latest version of the Mac operating system.
>
> If you still need macOS High Sierra, use this App Store link: [Get macOS High Sierra](https://itunes.apple.com/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?ls=1&mt=12).

The installer is downloaded in `/Applications` directory and is typically around 6GB in size. If needed, delete the installer currently present in `/Applications` directory.